# Div generated from a Repeater Control not in proper CSS Styling

Tags: asp.net, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am generating div elements via a **Repeater Control** . The DIV elements are generated , but the CSS of the same isn't in the proper format .

Here is my HTML Code :

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptr" runat="server">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 mb">
                <a href="VendorProfile.aspx">
                    <div class="twitter-panel pn">
                        <i class="fa fa-twitter fa-4x"></i>
                        <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Name") %>
                    </div>
                </a>
        </ItemTemplate>

    </asp:Repeater>
```

CSS :

```
.col-lg-4 {
    width: 33.33333333%;
  }

.col-md-4 {
    width: 33.33333333%;
  }
.col-sm-4 {
    width: 33.33333333%;
  }

.mb {
    margin-bottom: 25px;
}

.twitter-panel {
    background: #4fc1e9;
    text-align: center;
}

.pn {
    height: 250px;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.fa {
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 1;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

.fa-4x {
  font-size: 4em;
}
```

I am thinkng i should put float styling , but i am not sure about that. Also this is only sample , in my project i will have images in the background . So there will possibly no icons(as here it is the logo of twitter) .

And if this is the case should i make any custom css style only for this purpose ?

Here is my C# code :

```
public partial class PastOrders : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Session["vendor"] != null)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                ArrayList values = new ArrayList();

                values.Add(new Testing
                {
                    Name = "Caterer"
                });

                values.Add(new Testing
                {
                    Name = "Florist"
                });

                values.Add(new Testing
                {
                    Name = "Cab Services"
                });

                rptr.DataSource = values;
                rptr.DataBind();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Response.Redirect("VendorLogin.aspx");
        }
    }



    public class Testing
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

}
```

Comment: I think you are missing a closing `</div>` tag for your `<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 mb">`

Comment: how could i be soooo stupid >_< ... Thanks a ton for all your help !

Comment: no problem at all - I had to have a second look as i did not see it in your original question about the repeater control

Comment: that means i add a new property in the class from where i am generating the **Names** and access that in the aspx page ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are missing a closing `</div>` tag for your `<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 mb">`

Think that should do the trick!

Comment: Yea that worked! and if i want to randomise the color of generated divs and give specific images to them according to their name  , like a photo of flowers on "Florists" div and same for the others ..Is that possible?

Comment: you may consider extending your model by adding a new property `imageName`. Afterwards you could access this property on your aspx page

Comment: that means i add a new property in the class from where i am generating the Names and access that in the aspx page ?

Comment: So i do that and access it via `class= <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "CSS") %>` ??  in this way?

Comment: If `CSS` is the name of your new property - jep

Comment: okaay and should the quotes be added like : `class= " <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Name") %>" ' or simply without quotes : `class =  <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Name") %> `

Comment: I think single quotes should do it

Comment: class = ' <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Name") %>' .. is this the right way ?

Comment: yes sorry in hurry i copied it from the existing code.. Okay i will try that.. Thanks for all your time and help!

Answer (score 1):

write this styling in class md or u can make one more class if you are using this class in other and you want to show this style on this class only
.md {float:left;}

.md {display: inline-block;}

Comment: thank you for your help , but i had missed a closing `</div>` tag!